# How to make \dropchapter work with \chapter* (epigraph package)?

Tags: sectioning, epigraphs

I would like quite a long quote before my chapter title, a need which is perfectly fulfilled by using the `\epigraphhead` command provided with the epigraph package.

However, because the quote is very long, it interferes with my chapter title and text, like so:

[image]

In the documentation it is mentioned that this is likely to happen with long quotes, and that one can use the `\dropchapter` command to lower the chapter title, followed by the `\undodrop` command to make sure that the subsequent chapter titles are set normally again.

This is where my problem arises. Consider the following MWE (MWE1):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[bottom=2cm, top=2cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\dropchapter{15cm}
\chapter*{Introduction}
\epigraphhead[200]{\lipsum[1]}
\lipsum[1-3]
\undodrop

\chapter*{Method}
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

This still produces the following: 
[image]

In other words, nothing happens.

Now consider the following MWE (MWE2):

(note that the only difference with MWE1 is that the `\chapter*{}` commands have been changed to regular `\chapter{}` commands)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[bottom=2cm, top=2cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\dropchapter{15cm}
\chapter{Introduction}
\epigraphhead[200]{\lipsum[1]}
\lipsum[1-3]
\undodrop

\chapter{Method}
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

In other words, this is exactly what I need.

So I've already narrowed down where the problem arises (the `\chapter*{}` command), but I can't seem to figure out how to make the `\dropchapter` command work with MWE1. It is MWE1 that I want to use, I don't want the "Chapter X" prefixes in my document.

Does anyone have the answer? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `epigraph` package uses a horrible hack for realizing `\dropchapter`: it adds a vertical space in `\@chapapp`, which is not used when `\chapter*` is executed.

Here's a version that's specific for `book` and `report` (other classes may have different `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead` commands), but it works for both starred and unstarred `\chapter` commands.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[bottom=2cm, top=2cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\@epidrop}
\newcommand{\@epidropdefault}{50\p@} % the default in report
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{50\p@}{\@epidrop}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{50\p@}{\@epidrop}{}{}
\renewcommand{\dropchapter}[1]{\setlength{\@epidrop}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\undodrop}{\dropchapter{\@epidropdefault}}
\undodrop
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\dropchapter{15cm}

\chapter*{Introduction}
\epigraphhead[200]{\lipsum[1]}
\lipsum[1-3]

\chapter{Introduction}
\epigraphhead[200]{\lipsum[1]}
\lipsum[1-3]
\undodrop

\chapter{Method}
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

This works by substituting the vertical space hardwired in `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead` with a length parameter that we can control with a redefinition of `\dropchapter`.

Of course, using short epigraphs is the best solution.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it works like a charm! I would've never figured this out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

For KOMA-script classes, egreg's answer doesn't work. Instead one can use

`\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{15cm}}`

Full example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\let\defaultchapterheadstartvskip\chapterheadstartvskip
\renewcommand{\dropchapter}[1]{ 
  \renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{#1}}
}
\renewcommand{\undodrop}[0]{
  \renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\defaultchapterheadstartvskip}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\dropchapter{15cm}
\chapter{Introduction}
\epigraphhead[200]{\lipsum[1]}
\lipsum[1-3]
\undodrop

\chapter{Method}
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```